# Url not updating when new model is saved

Tags: ember.js

router.js

```
  this.route('claim', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:claim_id' });
  });
```

`claim.new` -> redirect to `claim.edit` with an empty model. `this.transitionTo('claim.edit', model);`

Initially, because the model is not saved we get: `index.html#/claim/null`

When we save the model, it continues to display as `index.html#/claim/null` instead of say `index.html#/claim/87`

Is there a way to force the url to refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to force the URL to refresh is to force the route/page to refresh. You can use the [refresh method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) in your route to do that.

To understand why it doesn't update automatically, you have to understand how routes work and how Ember is separate from Ember Data (or any data persistence library).

First, you have to remember that Ember has no knowledge of Ember Data and the specifics of its object model. It just sees plain Ember objects. Ember Data models are more important than other models *to you*, but Ember isn't aware of that distinction.

Second, the routing in Ember is binding/observer aware. It doesn't watch for changes and update URL state accordingly. It calculates the URL once using the [serializer hook](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize), then it leaves it as that. It's not going to recalculate if your model changes in any way. It will only recalculate when it's refreshed.

Short story long, the part of your application that changes the ID of your model and the part that calculates the URL to use aren't aware of each other. You'll have to manually sync them up. Using the refresh method is probably easiest way to do that.

UPDATE: As Kitler pointed out, you can also transition to your route using the new model. It won't fire the `model` hook so it won't have to do any asynchronous work, but it will still update the URL.

Comment: Or he could `tranistionTo` and pass the saved model along with it

Comment: You're right. For some reason I thought that transitioning to the same route wouldn't do anything, but the model will technically be different. I'll update my answer.